# How can I make my dropdown list retain selected item if my list is in the ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

how can I make my dropdown list retain selected item if my list is in the ViewBag?

This first DropdownList works fine:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("searchString", Model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString(), Selected = s.ToString().Equals(selectedItemFromList) }))
```

And now I would like to have another DropdownList but instead of getting the list from the model I’m getting it from the view bag like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("searchString", new SelectList(ViewBag.someList, "text"), "select an item").. Again this works but I want the format like the first Dropdownlist that retains te selected value…something like this…

@Html.DropDownList("searchString", ViewBag.someList.Select(t=> new SelectListItem{ Text= t.ToString(),Value =t.ToString(),Selected =t.ToString().Equals(selectedItemFromList)}))
```

This doesn’t work because I’m getting my list from a viewbag I suspect. Is there a way to work with ViewBag to retain my selected list item like the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution does the same as mine except your's is implemented in the controller instead of the view.  I'm able to get my list to display but what I wanted was a way to keep the selected item of the list selected upon a revisit of the view.  My list is not a model property.  I created it in the controller then send it to the view via the viewbag.  The first example I showed was accessing the list as a model property.  The new list is accessed view the viewbag.  I wanted it to be configured like my first list which works ok.  Since my original post I've found a solution.

Since i needed the solution in the view finally did:

```
@Html.DropDownList("theString", listofinstructors.Select(tch => new SelectListItem { Text = tch.ToString(), Value = tch.ToString(), Selected = tch.ToString().Equals(somethingSelected) }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is initializing `ViewBag` in controller action...

controller

```
ViewBag.someList = Model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().WeekDays
                   .Select(s => new SelectListItem 
                   { 
                        Text = s.ToString(), 
                        Value = s.ToString(), 
                        Selected = s.ToString().Equals(selectedItemFromList)
                   }
```

view

```
@Html.DropDownList("someList", ViewBag.someList as SelectList, "select one")
```

you can initialize selected value in controller side.

Check [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) for examples...